# How do you do dynamic insert queryes with node posgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

If I have columns A, B, C, and D and only A is required what's the best way to build an INSERT query for node postgres? I can do it with conditionals or dynamic strings like `INSERT table ${keys} VALUES ${values)` but I'm not sure if that's ok.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was a a complete UPDATE with all the columns I want updated using the built-in variable substation ($1, $2, ...) in the query. Then I update by first selecting the old record, and using the spread operator to merge the new values over top of the old values. This way my PUT can accept partial records:

`const data = { ...oldRecord, ...newValuesFromPUT};`

For INSERT I just let the built in mechanics convert undefined to NULL and as expected NOT NULL columns throw an error if empty.